# (requested by the login. The login failed.) in a service based database

Tags: c#, sql-server

i'm using a service based SQL server in my windows form application
i want to use app.config file to store connection string

in my app, every thing work well when i drag a "sqlconnection" in to my form and use it in the code! but when i changed it with a connection string it can not connect to database and app stop with login failed error

i need to know that how can i add user athuntication to service based sqlserver in vs2013?

[image: here is some images of my problem!]

Comment: Does your sql server have just "." for Data Source? Does not have an instance?

Comment: its also "." in sqlconnection1 , is it wrong? but it work there!

Comment: It's not wrong, but sql server usually have an instance, like ".\SQLSERVER", or ".\SQLEXPRESS", just to be sure that the data source is correct.

Comment: yes data sources is correct,I copy the connection string from sqlconnection1 that already work